# Receiving "Cannot PUT" from server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a PUT route based on a tutorial I was following for the MERN stack.

Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const toDoSchema = new Schema({
    //taskNum: {type: Number, required: true},
    task: {type: String, required: true},
    //progress: {type: String, required: true},
    //difficulty: {type: Number, required: true}
});

const toDo = mongoose.model("toDo", toDoSchema);

module.exports = toDo
```

API:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//ToDo Model
const ToDo= require('../../models/toDo');

// @route   GET api/toDo
// @desc    GET all to dos
// @access  Public 
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    ToDo.find()
    .sort({ taskNum: -1 })
    .then(toDo => res.json(toDo))
});

// @route   POST api/toDo
// @desc    create a new to dos
// @access  Public 
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const newToDo = new ToDo({
        //taskNum: req.body.taskNum,
        task: req.body.task,
        //progress: req.body.progress,
        //difficulty: req.body.difficulty
    })

    newToDo.save().then(toDo => res.json(toDo));
});

// @route   DELETE api/toDo/:id
// @desc    Delete a to do
// @access  Public 
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
        ToDo.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(toDo => toDo.remove().then(() => res.json( {success: true } )))
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json( {success: false } ));
});

// @route   UPDATE api/toDo/:id
// @desc    Update a to do
// @access  Public 
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
        ToDo.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(toDo => toDo.set({ task: req.body.task }).then(() => res.json( {success: true } )))
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json( {success: false} ));
});


module.exports = router;
```

I am testing out the code in Postman and keep getting the Cannot PUT error message.

[Postman Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ4pW.png)

All the other routes work perfectly fine and I am just stuck at this end point. Any ideas on what I should change?

Comment: Post your code here so we cab read it. Be specific with your question (refer to the code).

Comment: Sorry about that, re-posted with my code

Comment: have you change the into put in postman

Comment: I also suggest telling us the exact error message text.  Especially with HTTP, there will be an HTTP error code if something went wrong at the protocol level with the request.  But there will be a JavaScript error if something exceptional happened.

Comment: It should work, please give a screenshot of your postman failed request.

Comment: posted the error screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are sending data through the **body**.Try to log the values of **req.params.id** and **req.body.task** and try something like this. use findOneAndUpdate

```
// @route   UPDATE api/toDo/:id
// @desc    Update a to do
// @access  Public 
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    ToDo.findOneAndUpdate({ id: req.params.id }, { $set: { task: req.body.task } }, { new: true }, 
        function(err, doc) {
              if(!err){
                  res.json( {success: true } )
               }
         });
}).catch(err => res.status(404).json( {success: false} ));
```